# Redirect users to specific aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication

I have created a website using `Visual Studio 2010` and I have several hundred users, each with their own dedicated page. After the user logs in, I want them to be redirected to their dedicated page. For example, user 2460, after logging in, should be redirected to `2460.aspx`. I cant seem to figure out how to accomplish this effectively. The farthest I've gotten is to redirect everyone to the same page after logging in. Any thoughts?

Comment: what about Response.Redirec(userid+".aspx");

Comment: They have dedicated physical pages? Was there a benefit in doing it this way instead of having one page/control that loads up the appropriate data based on the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the page that they have to go to, just build the URL and do a `Response.Redirect` to it.

```
var userId = GetUserId(); // However you get this value

// After they log In
Response.Redirect("~/" + userId + ".aspx");
```

Comment: Great this got me where I needed to go. Thanks

Comment: @GreenDeveloper, no problem. If it solved your problem, please remember to accept it as the answer by clicking on the checkmark.